# PHP Parse error with valid JSON

Tags: php, json, decode

I validated this JSON with JSONLint and when line 25 of my script runs which looks like:

```
$temp = json_decode( $obj->hints,true );
```

I am getting a:

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected 'hintsacross' (T_STRING) in **C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\crosswords\query.blockouts.php** on line **25**

coming out the script. I am wondering how to make this parse error go away. This is the JSON:

```
{
   "hintsacross": [ 
         { "number": "1", "hinttext": "Hurt", "hintsquare": "A1" }, 
         { "number": "5", "hinttext": "Make a selection", "hintsquare": "A6" },
         { "number": "8", "hinttext": "Frank", "hintsquare": "A10" } ], 
   "hintsdown": [ 
         { "number": "1", "hinttext": "First Greek letter", "hintsquare": "A1" },
         { "number": "2", "hinttext": "Used footnotes", "hintsquare": "A2" }, 
         { "number": "3", "hinttext": "Listened to", "hintsquare": "A3" } ] 
}
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: This is a parse error of your PHP, **NOT** of the JSON.

Comment: There must be a way to get the parse error to go away since the JSON is formatted properly?

Comment: I'm not sure if it matters but my JSON is stored in a database field inline.

Comment: I just changed line 25 to   $temp = json_decode( (string)$obj->hints,true ); and things seem to be working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make sure you are passing a valid string to the `json_decode` function.

```
 $myArray = json_decode("{"k":1}",1); // wont work as the input json string breaks
```

and put the string like

```
 $myArray = json_decode('{"k":1}',1); // works
```

Comment: $temp = json_decode( (string)$obj->hints,true ); seems to be the answer

Comment: yes. 1st parameter to [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) should be a string